# modify an array inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the next array:

```
$array = array
(
'body' => 'array ("color" => "blue", "font-weight" => "bold")',
'div' => 'array ("color" => "red", "background" => "blue")'
);
```

And i want, for example to edit the `body`'s `"color" => "blue"` to `"color" => "black"`.

As extracting the data from those arrays and printing it out was easy:

```
foreach ($array as $element_name => $element_style){
    echo $array_part_name . '{';
    foreach ($array_part_style as $property_name => $property){
        echo $property_name . ': ' . $property . '; '
    }
    echo '}'
}
```

And I guess it should result just like css, but how do i edit that specific part? (mentioned above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, do you want your sub *arrays* to be strings? Because if you want a multidimensional array you would do this:

```
$array = array
(
    'body' => array("color" => "blue", "font-weight" => "bold"),
    'div' => array ("color" => "red", "background" => "blue")
);
```

And then you can change the body color like this:

```
$array['body']['color'] = 'black';
```

And if you want to loop through all the items and subitems you will do it like this:

```
foreach ($array as $selector => $properties) {

    echo $selector.' {';

    foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.': '.$value.';';
    }

    echo '}';
}
```

Comment: ooh.. i am not really into multidimensional array, like i don't really get them... i guess that's what i want, i'll try ty

Comment: but how do i do this if i don't actually now the sub array's property_name or property? like with a foreach

Comment: like `foreach ($array as $element_name => $element_style){
 foreach ($element_style as $property_name => $property){
  $array[$element_name][$property_name] = "black";
 }
}`